# From if/else to Stream using Map.Entry

Tags: java, java-stream

Could you help me please to convert this `for` loop including `if`/`else` to using `Stream`?

```java
public Integer months() {

  String desiredObject;
  Map<String, Integer> monthDays = new HashMap<>();

  monthDays.put("March", 31);
  monthDays.put("April", 30);

  Set<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> entrySet = monthDays.entrySet();

  for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> pair : entrySet) {
    if (desiredObject.equals(pair.getKey())) {
      return pair.getValue();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
return entrySet.stream()
  .filter(pair -> desiredObject.equals(pair.getKey()))
  .map(Entry::getValue)
  .findAny().orElse(null);
```

or, alternatively just

```java
return monthDays.get(desiredObject);
```